# How to add spaces around a substring if spaces aren't already there yet?

Tags: php, parsing, spaces, emoticons

Example input string: `test:)test:)test:) :) test:p test`
Wanted output string: `test :) test :) test :) :) test :p test`

As you can see in the example above, I want to parse the string and produce an output string with spaces added around all predefined smiley codes.

I was trying to do this with a couple of loops but in the end it didn't work 100% as expected and it was terribly slow on big documents.

So I'm wondering what would be the best and most efficient way to do this kind of parsing with PHP?

Comment: regular expressions. learn them, enjoy them and find out that it's really easy to do it in one line of `preg_replace`

Comment: I tried doing this with preg_replace() before but it didn't work for some reason. Could you help me out here?

Comment: @Prinzhorn I tried with '$text=preg_replace('/([^ ]):\\)([^ ])/i', '$1 :) $2', $text)' but doesn't work. Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: why not added the spaces no matter what and then just replace multiple spaces with a single space

Answer (score 2):

Nested replacement:

```
preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", 
    str_replace( Array( ":)", ":p" ),
        Array( " :) ", " :p " ), $str) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$lspace =   str_replace(":"," :","test:)test:)test:) :) test:p");
$rspace =    str_replace(")",") ",$lspace);
$out    =    preg_replace("/\s\s+/"," ",$rspace);


echo $out;
?>
```

output:`test :) test :) test :) :) test :p`

Answer (score 0):

Instead regular expression you can use `str_replace` function.
PHP function `str_replace` can receive arrays as parameters, so you can try this:

```
$input = 'test:)test:)test:) :) test:p test';
$smileys = array( ':)', ':p' );
$smileys_with_spaces = array( ' :)', ' :p' );
$output = str_replace( $smileys_with_spaces, $smileys, $input ); // test:) :) -> test:):)
$output = str_replace( $smileys, $smileys_with_spaces, $input ); // test:):) -> test :) :)
```

Comment: This does not look like a usable solution because it will add excessive spaces. It will, for example, add spaces to smiley codes that already have spaces arround them.

Comment: Regular expressions are better way. @xdazz gave more appropriated solution.

Comment: Just remove excess spaces by `str_replace( '<space><space>', '<space>', $input );`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$str = "test:)test:)test:) :) test:p test";
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[^a-z\s])|(?<=[^a-z]{2})(?=[a-z])/', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: This one won't work when two smileycodes are next to each other. So with $str being ":):)", it's not adding any space

Answer (score 0):

Update with support for N smileys

```
$smile = array(':)', ':p');

//Escape smiley chars for use in rx
foreach($smile as &$s) {
    $s = preg_quote($s, '/');
}unset($s);

$rx = implode('|', $smile);

$str = 'test:)test:)test:) :) test:p test';

$str = preg_replace('/ *('.$rx.') */', ' $1 ', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/('.$rx.') +/', '$1 ', $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: This one works except that it will add too much spaces if two smileycodes are next to each other. for example ":):)" would become "<space>:)<space><space>:)<space>" while I need ":)<space>:)" in this example.

Comment: any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: This update still won't fix excessive spaces at the beginning or ending of the string. And I can't use trim() because if the original has spaces at the beginning or ending, it has to stay that way.

Comment: example input  would be simple: ":):)". This would get a space at the beginning and ending with your code. But I need it to only get 1 extra space: between the smiley codes only.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to not have extra spaces at the beginning/end, try this:

```
$str = ':):)test:)test:)test:) :) test:p:) test';
$codes = array(
    ':)', ':p', // Add smileys here.
);

// We build the $regexp automatically
$regexp = array();
foreach($codes as $smiley)
    $regexp[] = preg_quote($smiley, '#');
$regexp = implode('|', $regexp);
// Afterwards, we might replace the above with $regexp = 'VERYCOMPLICATEDSYNTAX';

// Split the string at smileys, trimming the smileys as we go,
// and returning an array of smiley-and-non-smiley parts, except for empty ones
$parts = preg_split("#\s*($regexp)\s*#", $str, -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

// The new delimiter is a single space.
$str = implode(' ', $parts);
```

Note that I have used the whitespace matcher `\s` instead of a literal space; this can have unwanted results if you have line feeds in the original string. If that is the case, replace "`\s`" with a " " literal space.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a more elegant solution, but the below code should work

```
$patterns = array();
$replacements = array();

$str = ':) test :)test:) test :)';

$smileys = array(':)', ':p');

foreach($smileys as &$s) {
    $s = preg_quote($s, '/');
}unset($s);
$escaped_smiley = implode('|', $smileys);

$patterns[] = '/([^\s])('.$escaped_smiley.')([^\s])/'; // no spaces
$patterns[] = '/([\s])('.$escaped_smiley.')([^\s])/';  // space on left
$patterns[] = '/([^\s])('.$escaped_smiley.')([\s])/';  // space on right

$patterns[] = '/^('.$escaped_smiley.')([\s])/';   // line starting, space succeding
$patterns[] = '/^('.$escaped_smiley.')([^\s])/';  // line starting, no space
$patterns[] = '/([\s])('.$escaped_smiley.')$/';   // line ending, space preceeding
$patterns[] = '/([^\s])('.$escaped_smiley.')$/';  // line ending, no space

$replacements[] = '$1 $2 $3'; // no spaces 
$replacements[] = '$1$2 $3';  // space on left
$replacements[] = '$1 $2$3';  // space on right

$replacements[] = ' $1$2';    // line starting
$replacements[] = ' $1 $2';   // line starting
$replacements[] = '$1$2 ';    // line ending
$replacements[] = '$1 $2 ';   // line ending


$result = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
echo str_replace(' ', '^', $result);
```

[Edited with code borrowed from @Prinzhorn]

Comment: This fails an input string like ':)test:)test:)test:)'

Comment: the output is :)test :) test :) test:) .. notice the missing spaces at the end of the first emoticon code and before the last one.

Comment: @Erik edited code to take into account line starting and ending. Also removed the `foreach` loop with `implode` and replaced quoted smileys with quoting `foreach` loop, from @Prinzhorn.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not solved the problem yet, I came up with a solution that may work. First explode the string with the spaces as delimiters, replace the smileys with additional spaces and rejion them with implode.

Check [php fiddle](http://codepad.org/8STsYwGa) for the implementation.